# "the growth of he and his sister" in this sentence from the Guardian

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, possessives, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case

Just read this line on the Guardian:

> He dismantles his bedroom and helps tidy the house, daubing white paint over the pencil marks on the doorframe which have measured the **growth of he and his sister** from infancy until now.

Can't figure out how **he** is correct here. Shouldn't it be **him**?

Comment: It's either a typo or written by a non-English speaker. The Grauniad used to be famous for its typos.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, it should, but it's another example of the instability of English pronouns.

Comment: Talking here of instability of the English pronouns is very gracious from your part (+1). Although I'm not at all a prescriptivist I find certain things are mistakes that can show lack of understanding from the writer's point of view and hinder the comprehension of a sentence  and coming from a journalist of a quality paper it is not reassuring for the English language. Not special to English either I must say.

Comment: I see this kind of variation in pronoun use as a continuation of the erosion of pronominal inflections that began centuries ago. Why, after all, do we not still use the original accusative form of the third person masculine singular of the personal pronoun? That was not _him_ (which was the dative), but _hine_.

Comment: I see your point.

Comment: @Laure The Guardian has come a long way since it got nicknamed 'Grauniad', because of all its typos. And if 'he' for 'him' is the only typographical error (which is probably what it is) in any vast edition, they are not doing too badly.

Comment: @Laure I find it disturbing when the BBC recommends such constructions as 'It's good night from John and I.' I can't argue it's 'wrong', because I'll say "It's me," which is just as rule-breaking as what they use.

Comment: As Huddleston and Pullum write, ‘why should we simply assume that the grammatical rules for case assignment cannot differentiate between a coordinated and a non-coordinated pronoun?

Comment: The lack of declination of English often challenges understanding and limits our ability to use a wider variety of positional emphasis. Resisting further loss of case is worth doing (even if you are not a strict prescriptivist).

Comment: I don't believe that for one minute, but we can hardly pursue the point here.

Comment: @bib, Barrie: Maybe not *indefinitely*, but I and countless others completely endorse your "equanimitous" position (or should that be ***me*** and the rest of the right-thinking Anglophonic world?). Pronominal inflections are too deeply embedded in English to be discarded even over generations - but they're largely redundant, and it certainly doesn't bother me if a relatively significant minority use forms that are considered "incorrect" according to grammatical principles which are often in the (agonisingly slow) process of becoming obsolete.

Answer (score 4):

"Him" is better than "he," because it's the object pronoun, but is still not idiomatic. Simplify the sentence to check; "pencil marks measured the growth of him?" No! "Pencil marks measured his growth." The conventional way to add the sister would be "and that of his sister." That could make the sentence above correct:

> He dismantles his bedroom and helps tidy the house, daubing white paint over the pencil marks on the doorframe which have measured his growth, and that of his sister, from infancy until now.

but even clunkier. The sentence should have been rewritten entirely. Going through contortions to make something work grammatically is usually a sign that the sentence structure itself is becoming problematic!

Answer (score 2):

The error has since been rectified by the *[Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2014/jan/21/sundance-boyhood-review-richard-linklater)*

> At the start of Richard Linklater's extraordinary, deeply moving Boyhood, seven-year-old Mason (Ellar Coltrane) ups-sticks for Houston. He dismantles his bedroom and helps tidy the house, daubing white paint over the pencil marks on the doorframe which have measured the growth of **him and his sister** (Lorelei Linklater) from infancy until now.

The pronoun, *him*, is used because it is the ***object*** of the verb *measure*.

But it is also possible to say,

> ... which have measured **his height**, and that of his sister from infancy until now.
>    ... which have measured his height, and **his sister's** [height] from infancy until now.

Answer (score 1):

For me it's either a typo or a grammar mistake. A gradual change of the system can be seen in sentences of the type It's me, but after prepositions the accusative forms of the personal pronouns are still in use: for him, to her. I take "he" simply for a typo and would not speak of erosion of "pronominal inflections". I would say the accusative (me/him/her/us/them) as object or after pronouns is so stable that there is no cause for worries about the collapse of the English grammar system.